# What is source data for the report generated by junitreport ant task?

Tags: ant, junit

The JUnit official documentation states:

> *junitreport collects individual xml files generated by the JUnit task using the nested  element.*

Other part of the same page states:

```
<junitreport todir="./reports">   
 <fileset dir="./reports">
    <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>  
 </fileset>   
    <report format="frames" todir="./report/html"/> 
</junitreport>
```

> *would generate a TESTS-TestSuites.xml file in the directory reports
>   and generate the default framed report in the directory report/html.*

Let's say, I have file TEST-all.xml generated by junit task in the "reports" directory. I want to use it as data source for junitreport task:

```
<fileset dir="./reports">
    <include name="TEST-all*.xml"/>
</fileset>
```

I would expect html report based on my data will be generated.

I tried to do it. Empty TESTS-TestSuites.xml file was generated and as a result empty html file.

Two documentation statements I quoted above somehow contradict each other: the first one says it will use already generated files to create a report and the second one says it will generate new file. Can somebody explain how it works? How can I control what data source will be used to generate html report?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try running ant with -debug.  I suspect

```
 <include name="TEST-all*.xml"/>
```

is not matching any files. Please try with

```
<fileset dir="./reports">
    <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
</fileset>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out what was the problem: file TEST-all.xml was generated in wrong format. It seems the correct format is:

```
    <testsuite>
      <testcase classname="..." name="..." ...>
        <properties>
          <property name="..."/>
        </properties>
      </testcase>
    </testsuite>
```

It didn't solve the problem completely though. The html report is still not generated properly:

1. In spite the fact that file TESTS-TestSuits.xml is not empty now and contains all necessary tests' information, main page of HTML report (index.html) still shows 0 tests.
2. If I click the link  in Tests column (0 in this case) it opens list of tests, but if I try to open individual test in this page, I get "File not found" error.

I suspect the problem is still with the format of TEST-all.xml. I was looking for the description of the format, but found only pieces of information here and there. Any ideas?